# Unit testing two objects which return a matrix (java)

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, junit

I'm trying to create a JUnit test with two objects that return a 2D array/matrix, here is my constructor:

```
public Matrix(int[][] array) {
    this.matrix = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length); }
```

Here is my test code:

```
@Test
void addValue() {
    int[][] array = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}};
    int[][] newArray = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}};

    Matrix result = new Matrix(array);
    Matrix expected = new Matrix(newArray);

    assertEquals(expected,result.addValue(0,4));

}
```

addValueInSpecificLine is a function I created, in this case, it adds the value 4 in line 0.

Here is the error of my test:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: Matrix@3c0a50da<Array{array=[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3]]}> but was: Matrix@646be2c3<Array{array=[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3]]}>
Expected :Array{array=[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3]]}
Actual   :Array{array=[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3]]}
```

The expected is the same as the actual, but for some reason the test is false.

Any advice?

Comment: I recommend taking a look at [`Arrays::equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(int%5B%5D,int%5B%5D)) and [`Assert::assertArrayEquals`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertArrayEquals-int:A-int:A-). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37627340/junit-assert-double-arrays/37627615).

Answer (score 1):

You should define `Matrix.equals()` like this.

```
public class Matrix {
    final int[][] matrix;

    public Matrix(int[][] array) {
        this.matrix = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
    }

    public Matrix addValue(int row, int value) {
        int size = matrix[row].length;
        int[] newRow = Arrays.copyOf(matrix[row], size + 1);
        newRow[size] = value;
        matrix[row] = newRow;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof Matrix m
            && Arrays.deepEquals(matrix, m.matrix);
    }
}

@Test
void addValue() {
    int[][] array = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}};
    int[][] newArray = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}};

    Matrix result = new Matrix(array);
    Matrix expected = new Matrix(newArray);

    assertEquals(expected, result.addValue(0, 4));
}
```